# Difference betweeen RFC 3548 and RFC 4648

Tags: base64

I am translating some `Python` code to `C++`. Parts of the code use `base 64 encoding.`

The `Python code` uses `RFC 3548 encoding`, but the `C++ library` I am using only has `RFC 4648`.

I understand that `RFC 4648` obsolete `RFC 3548`, but I could not find out where they differ. I also wrote a program in Python and one in C++ to encode the same plain-text file, and they produce the same output.

**So for base 64 encoding, what are the differences between RFC 3548 and 4648?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Executive summary:** the text of the standard has changed in minor ways without changing the behavior it describes.

Details:

[The IETF page for RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) contains a link to [a diff from RFC 3548 to RFC 4648](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url2=rfc4648). Looking over the diff, I see that apparently all of the changes before part 11 (ISO C99 Implementation of Base64) are non-functional grammatical changes.

Part 11 is changed to provide a link to an external implementation rather than providing an implementation inline because “The code could not be included in this RFC for procedural reasons ([RFC 3978 section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3978#section-5.4)).” The specific reason is that the C implementation in RFC 3548 included a copyright notice different than the one allowed by RFC 3978.

After that, there are more grammatical changes, some references have been updated, and the copyright, disclaimer, and acknowledgements have been updated.